# Full-height sidebar

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have the following page with sidebar: https://www.slagerijrudi.be/product/broodje-ham/

I was wondering if there is a simple way to make my sidebar have the same height of the content next to the sidebar. So the sidebar should stretch from header to footer, instead of stopping halfway the page.

Comment: This question isn't really a good fit for stackoverflow.  It's best if you can create a minimal example of the problem on here along with what you've tried. (A simple link to a remote site is always discouraged.) This gives us something to work with and ensures that your question and subsequent answers will be useful to others in the future.  That being said, you should be able to pull off what you're trying to do by adding `display:flex` to `.wf-container-main` and `height:100%` to `.sidebar-content`.  Note that you may need to run that through an auto-prefixer for IE compatibility.

Comment: @JosephMarikle thanks Joseph, will keep this in mind for future questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to allow the `aside` (or sidebar) to reach its full height, you can make it have an absolute position. Do remember though to turn it off for smaller screen sizes (where you'd want to collapse the sidebar). The best design practice at the moment is to declare specific behaviour for larger screens: `@media screen and (min-size:667px) { .. your code for big screens here .. }`

Add the following to solve the issue:

```
.wf-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Edit: as a comment on the question put it, a flexbox is a neater solution, but not a 'quick fix'.